# where can I find box2d's full references & explanations?

Tags: box2d, document

I'm learning Box2D's joints & reading the 'so-called' manual here :

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

But for some parts, such as 'distanceJoint', they gave me suggestions instead of full-feature-list, without explainations.

I spent hours testing the suggested features but have not yet figured out what the features do, or how to use them. (eg: the property named "collideConnected" of DistanceJoint) And I even wonder if all the available features are listed there or I must find some myself.

Thus, I wonder if they have a more detailed documentations, like MSDN, somewhere. - or what I have at  this moment are all I can deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some more detailed description [there](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-overview). If you need *documentation* (not manual), then you can go [there online](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/annotated.html), or download Box2D source and compile it with Doxygen. It is also useful to look at Testbed, that distributing with Box2D sources.

Comment: The link to cocos2d solved the trouble with references, but not documentations yet. Anw, thanks a lot !